# Chart off screen

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have this org chart which is too wide and shows up off screen, the user might think the page is blank, is there a way to make the chart appear at the center of the screen when it loads?
Code as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1e/Logo_gayosso_sin_fondo_en_alta.gif">
<title>Organigrama</title>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        // [{v:'IDENTIFICADOR', f:<a href="LINK">'PUESTO</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">NOMBRE</div>'}, 'A QUIÉN REPORTA', '']
        data.addRows([
          [{v:'CEO', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Carlos Lukac</div>'}, '', ''],
          [{v:'DRH', f:'<a href="#"><a href="/FichasDescriptivas/DRH.html" >Director RH</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Luis Arturo Flores</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
          [{v:'DNCC', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional de Capillas y Cementerios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ursula Gartz</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
          [{v:'DO', f:'<a href="#">Director Operaciones</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Sosa</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
          [{v:'CFO', f:'<a href="#">CFO</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Octavio Trejo</div>'}, 'CEO', 'CFO'],
          [{v:'DNVP', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional Ventas de Previsión</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Everardo García</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
          [{v:'DRI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director de Relaciones Institucionales</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Francisco Carriedo</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
          [{v:'DPM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Planeación y Marketing</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Oscar Chávez</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
          [{v:'GDO', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente de Desarrollo Organizacional</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jeannette González</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
          [{v:'GerenteVacante', f:'<a href="#">Gerente de Reclutamiento y Selección</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vacante</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
          [{v:'HectorGarcia', f:'<a href="#">Gerente Administración de RH</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Hector García Piñón</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
          [{v:'BenjaminM', f:'<a href="#">Gerente de Relaciones Públicas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Benjamín Martínez</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
          [{v:'Gaudencia', f:'<a href="#">Gerente Servicios Complementarios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Gaudencia García</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
          [{v:'DRCVM', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Valle de México</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Víctor Hernández</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
          [{v:'DRCB', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Bajío</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jesús Campos</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
          [{v:'DRCN', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sergio Nieto</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
          [{v:'GT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Telemarketing</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fernando Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'GOC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Operación Comercial</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ignacio Rosado</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'DRVM1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 1</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'DRVM2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 2</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Juan Salvador Díaz</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'DRVPN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle Pacífico/Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ricardo Lemus</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'DRVB', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Bajío</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sinuhé Margarito</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'DRVM1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 1</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
          [{v:'DITR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Impuestos, Tesorería y Riesgos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ramón Laguna</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DAI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Auditoría Interna</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo García</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Jurídico</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Carrillo</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DPF', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Planeación FInanciera</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guillermo Perea</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Contraloría</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Vallejo</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DRTI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director de Tecnología de Informática</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isela Montenegro</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Gabriela Cruz</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'DCZ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Cobranza</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Pérez</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
          [{v:'GS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente de Seguridad</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Rogelio Mendiola</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
          [{v:'GGI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente General INTECSA</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús González</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
          [{v:'DNC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Nacional Cementerios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Rodríguez</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
          [{v:'DI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Infraestructura</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guillermo Alejandro</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
          [{v:'DNM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Nacional Mantenimiento</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Mauricio Valencia</div>'}, 'DO', ''],          
          [{v:'GIN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Inteligencia de Negocio</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Arriola</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],          
          [{v:'GEC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Estrategia Comercial</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fernando Flores</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],          
          [{v:'GDNM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo Negocios MKT</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yoani Lorenzo</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],          
          [{v:'GA1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guadalupe Duarte</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ignacio Benitez</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA3', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Morales</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA4', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isabel Butanda</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA5', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús Loera</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA6', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús Lira</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA7', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Obed López</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA8', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Pizaña</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GA9', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Guadalupe Bueno</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GNAE', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Nacional de Activos Estratégicos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandra Mendoza</div>'}, 'DA', ''],          
          [{v:'GTI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Tesorería</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Luis Arámbula</div>'}, 'DITR', ''],          
          [{v:'GCC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capilla Cuernavaca</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ruben Navarro</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Sullivan</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Antonio Ruíz</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Colima</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">teresita de Jesús Gutiérrez</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCSM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Santa Mónica</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Rodolfo Vega</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCFC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Félix Cuevas/LM</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Patrick Hill</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Comercial Valle México</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Teresa del Río</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Acapulco</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Luis Parra</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCAGS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Aguascalientes</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isidro Villanueva</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Guadalajara</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Liliana Gutiérrez</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Irapuato</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marina Carreón</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios León</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Verónica Navarrete</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Morelia</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Martín Huerta</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCMTY', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Monterrey</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Beatríz Becerril</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCMXI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Mexicali</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Nora Andrade</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Reynosa</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Diana Cruz</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCTIJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Tijuana</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Abril Solis</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],          
          [{v:'GCCT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Aracely Contreras</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],          
          [{v:'DCCPT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Convenios Corporativos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Roberto Valdez</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
          [{v:'GCCT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Aracely Contreras</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
          [{v:'DVPCA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Canales Alternos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yasmín Vedia</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
          [{v:'DVPVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Del Valle</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Cisneros</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
          [{v:'DVPP', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Poniente</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alberto Munguía</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
          [{v:'DVPA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Acapulco</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Marroquín</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
          [{v:'DVPG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Guardias</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Nidia González</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
          [{v:'DVPN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Adriana Rosales</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
          [{v:'DVPS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Sur</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Paula Alfaro</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
          [{v:'GDV1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Francisco Palacios</div>'}, 'DVPCA', ''],
          [{v:'GDV2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Arturo González</div>'}, 'DVPCA', ''],
          [{v:'GDV3', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yadira Ramírez</div>'}, 'DVPP', ''],
          [{v:'GDVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas/Módulos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Carreón</div>'}, 'DVPG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV4', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Carlos Rodríguez</div>'}, 'DVPN', ''],
          [{v:'DVPGDL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Guadalajara</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alberto Lomelí</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
          [{v:'DVPMXI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Mexicali</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Álvaro Aldana</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
          [{v:'DVPR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Reynosa</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Lucio</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
          [{v:'DVPTIJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Tijuana</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Hernández</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
          [{v:'DVPT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Álvarez</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
          [{v:'DVPAGS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Aguascalientes</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Mario Ayala</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
          [{v:'DVPL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión León</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Belmont</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
          [{v:'DVPI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Irapuato</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Luna</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
          [{v:'DVPMS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Monterrey Zona Sur</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sandra Tapia</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
          [{v:'DVPMN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Monterrey Zona Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Federico Montes de Oca</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
          [{v:'DVPM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Morelia</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Maria Venzor</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
          [{v:'GDVG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas/Guardias</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sandra Pulido</div>'}, 'DVPG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV5', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Eduardo Huerta</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV6', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Claudia Díaz</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV7', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Lizbeth Negrete</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV8', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ericka Armeria</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV9', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Álvarez</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
          [{v:'GDV10', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ana García</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
          [{v:'GDV11', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Diana Corral</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
          [{v:'GDV12', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Piedra</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
          [{v:'GDV13', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Juan González</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
          [{v:'GDV14', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marina Ríos</div>'}, 'DVPT', ''],
          [{v:'GDV15', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fabiola Castruita</div>'}, 'DVPT', ''],
          [{v:'GDV16', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Daniel Martínez</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
          [{v:'GDV17', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Espinosa</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
          [{v:'GDV18', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Benavides</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
          [{v:'GDV19', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Wong</div>'}, 'DVPMN', ''],
          [{v:'GDV20', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Martha Álvarez</div>'}, 'DVPM', '']
          
          
          
          
        ]);
        // Create the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        // Listen for 'ready' event
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      chart.collapse(i, true);
    }
  });
        // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true, allowCollapse: true});
      }
   </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <div id='chart_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to share a solution I wrote recently based on two other posts provided by @WhiteHat .  It fixes the bug he mentioned using a different approach but combining his ideas. 
[Chart off screen (answer below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235381/7763687)
[Send Email Link from Google Org Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38807797/7763687)

1. Javascript library called [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) is used for grouping the children by parent ID.  This array is used to add/remove children on demand when a node is clicked.
2. Click event on the visualization container is used to Expand/Collapse each node instead of the google select event listener.  This allows a hyperlink to be included in the formatted content of each node.

Many thanks to Mr. @WhiteHat for helping the community with his expertise.

Here is the full demo:

```js
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  //#region Grouped Parents w/Children
  /*
  [ { v: "2-G02", f: "<div>" }, "2", ""]
  [ { v: ID, f: "<div>" }, PARENT, TOOLTIP]
  */

  const group_byParent = _(dataTable)
    .groupBy((o) => {
      return o[1];
    })
    .value();
  //console.log(group_byParent);
  //#endregion

  //#region Push level 0 parents
  const nodesVisible = [
    //Collector for visible nodes to redraw chart on expand/collapse.
    [
      { id: "name", label: "Name", type: "string" },
      { id: "manager", label: "Manager", type: "string" },
      { type: "string", role: "tooltip", p: { html: true } },
    ],
  ];

  const nodesLevel0 = _.filter(dataTable, (o) => {
    return o[1] === "";
  }); //where ParentID o[1] is blank
  nodesLevel0.forEach((n) => {
    nodesVisible.push(n);
  });

  //#endregion

  let data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(nodesVisible);
  const container = document.getElementById("chart_div");
  const chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(container);
  const options = { allowHtml: true, allowCollapse: true };

  const selection = { row: 0, column: null };
  container.addEventListener(
    "click",
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      //GATEKEEPER - if an anchor tag (<a>), then follow the address
      if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
        window.open(e.target.href, "_blank"); // OR location.href = e.target.href;
        return false;
      }

      // Is the node selected? Then record the selection.
      //  NOTE: clicking node the 2nd time in a row deselects it(so.getSelection returns undefined).
      const isNodeSelected = chart.getSelection()[0] ? true : false;
      isNodeSelected ? (selection.row = chart.getSelection()[0].row) : null;

      const { row } = selection;
      const nodeSelectionID = data.getValue(row, 0);
      const nodeChildren = chart.getChildrenIndexes(row);
      const hasChildren = nodeChildren.length > 0 ? true : false;

      if (!hasChildren) {
        //EXPAND NODE
        const nodeChildrenToAdd = group_byParent[nodeSelectionID] || [];
        nodeChildrenToAdd.forEach((c) => {
          nodesVisible.push(c);
        });
      }

      if (hasChildren) {
        //COLLAPSE NODE

        const whileCollector = [];
        const childrenToRemove = [];

        //Step 1 - Find immediate children of selected parent node.
        const immediateChildren = group_byParent[nodeSelectionID] || [];
        immediateChildren.forEach((c) => {
          const childID = c[0].v;
          whileCollector.push(childID);
          childrenToRemove.push(childID);
        });

        //Step 2 - find all descendants of immediate children.
        while (whileCollector.length > 0) {
          const descendantID = whileCollector[0];
          const getChildren = group_byParent[descendantID] ? group_byParent[descendantID] : [];
          getChildren.forEach((c) => {
            const childID = c[0].v;
            whileCollector.push(childID);
            childrenToRemove.push(childID);
          });
          whileCollector.shift();
        }

        //Step 3 - remove all childrenToRemove from nodesVisible.
        const nodeChildrenRemoved = _.remove(nodesVisible, (o, i) => {
          const nodeID = o[0].v;
          const matchFound = _.indexOf(childrenToRemove, nodeID) !== -1 ? true : false;
          return matchFound;
        });
      }

      data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(nodesVisible);
      chart.draw(data, options);

      return false;
    },
    false
  ); //END container.addEventListener("click"

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script>

const dataTable = [
  [{v:'CEO', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Carlos Lukac</div>'}, '', ''],
  [{v:'DRH', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director RH</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Luis Arturo Flores</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
  [{v:'DNCC', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional de Capillas y Cementerios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ursula Gartz</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
  [{v:'DO', f:'<a href="#">Director Operaciones</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Sosa</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
  [{v:'CFO', f:'<a href="#">CFO</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Octavio Trejo</div>'}, 'CEO', 'CFO'],
  [{v:'DNVP', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional Ventas de Previsión</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Everardo García</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
  [{v:'DRI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director de Relaciones Institucionales</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Francisco Carriedo</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
  [{v:'DPM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Planeación y Marketing</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Oscar Chávez</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
  [{v:'GDO', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente de Desarrollo Organizacional</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jeannette González</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
  [{v:'GerenteVacante', f:'<a href="#">Gerente de Reclutamiento y Selección</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vacante</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
  [{v:'HectorGarcia', f:'<a href="#">Gerente Administración de RH</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Hector García Piñón</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
  [{v:'BenjaminM', f:'<a href="#">Gerente de Relaciones Públicas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Benjamín Martínez</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
  [{v:'Gaudencia', f:'<a href="#">Gerente Servicios Complementarios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Gaudencia García</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
  [{v:'DRCVM', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Valle de México</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Víctor Hernández</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
  [{v:'DRCB', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Bajío</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jesús Campos</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
  [{v:'DRCN', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sergio Nieto</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
  [{v:'GT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Telemarketing</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fernando Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'GOC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Operación Comercial</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ignacio Rosado</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'DRVM1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 1</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'DRVM2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 2</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Juan Salvador Díaz</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'DRVPN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle Pacífico/Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ricardo Lemus</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'DRVB', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Bajío</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sinuhé Margarito</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'DRVM1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 1</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
  [{v:'DITR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Impuestos, Tesorería y Riesgos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ramón Laguna</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DAI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Auditoría Interna</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo García</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Jurídico</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Carrillo</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DPF', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Planeación FInanciera</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guillermo Perea</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Contraloría</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Vallejo</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DRTI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director de Tecnología de Informática</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isela Montenegro</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Gabriela Cruz</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'DCZ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Cobranza</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Pérez</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
  [{v:'GS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente de Seguridad</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Rogelio Mendiola</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
  [{v:'GGI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente General INTECSA</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús González</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
  [{v:'DNC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Nacional Cementerios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Rodríguez</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
  [{v:'DI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Infraestructura</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guillermo Alejandro</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
  [{v:'DNM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Nacional Mantenimiento</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Mauricio Valencia</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
  [{v:'GIN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Inteligencia de Negocio</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Arriola</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],
  [{v:'GEC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Estrategia Comercial</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fernando Flores</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],
  [{v:'GDNM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo Negocios MKT</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yoani Lorenzo</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],
  [{v:'GA1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guadalupe Duarte</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ignacio Benitez</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA3', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Morales</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA4', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isabel Butanda</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA5', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús Loera</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA6', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús Lira</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA7', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Obed López</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA8', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Pizaña</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GA9', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Guadalupe Bueno</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GNAE', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Nacional de Activos Estratégicos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandra Mendoza</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
  [{v:'GTI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Tesorería</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Luis Arámbula</div>'}, 'DITR', ''],
  [{v:'GCC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capilla Cuernavaca</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ruben Navarro</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCCS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Sullivan</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Antonio Ruíz</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCCC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Colima</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">teresita de Jesús Gutiérrez</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCCSM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Santa Mónica</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Rodolfo Vega</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCCFC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Félix Cuevas/LM</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Patrick Hill</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Comercial Valle México</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Teresa del Río</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCCA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Acapulco</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Luis Parra</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
  [{v:'GCCAGS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Aguascalientes</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isidro Villanueva</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
  [{v:'GCCG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Guadalajara</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Liliana Gutiérrez</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
  [{v:'GCCI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Irapuato</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marina Carreón</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
  [{v:'GCCL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios León</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Verónica Navarrete</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
  [{v:'GCCM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Morelia</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Martín Huerta</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
  [{v:'GCCMTY', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Monterrey</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Beatríz Becerril</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
  [{v:'GCCMXI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Mexicali</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Nora Andrade</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
  [{v:'GCCR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Reynosa</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Diana Cruz</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
  [{v:'GCCTIJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Tijuana</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Abril Solis</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
  [{v:'GCCT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Aracely Contreras</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
  [{v:'DCCPT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Convenios Corporativos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Roberto Valdez</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
  [{v:'GCCT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Aracely Contreras</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
  [{v:'DVPCA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Canales Alternos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yasmín Vedia</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
  [{v:'DVPVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Del Valle</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Cisneros</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
  [{v:'DVPP', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Poniente</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alberto Munguía</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
  [{v:'DVPA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Acapulco</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Marroquín</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
  [{v:'DVPG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Guardias</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Nidia González</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
  [{v:'DVPN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Adriana Rosales</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
  [{v:'DVPS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Sur</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Paula Alfaro</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
  [{v:'GDV1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Francisco Palacios</div>'}, 'DVPCA', ''],
  [{v:'GDV2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Arturo González</div>'}, 'DVPCA', ''],
  [{v:'GDV3', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yadira Ramírez</div>'}, 'DVPP', ''],
  [{v:'GDVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas/Módulos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Carreón</div>'}, 'DVPG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV4', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Carlos Rodríguez</div>'}, 'DVPN', ''],
  [{v:'DVPGDL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Guadalajara</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alberto Lomelí</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
  [{v:'DVPMXI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Mexicali</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Álvaro Aldana</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
  [{v:'DVPR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Reynosa</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Lucio</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
  [{v:'DVPTIJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Tijuana</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Hernández</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
  [{v:'DVPT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Álvarez</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
  [{v:'DVPAGS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Aguascalientes</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Mario Ayala</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
  [{v:'DVPL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión León</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Belmont</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
  [{v:'DVPI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Irapuato</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Luna</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
  [{v:'DVPMS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Monterrey Zona Sur</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sandra Tapia</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
  [{v:'DVPMN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Monterrey Zona Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Federico Montes de Oca</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
  [{v:'DVPM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Morelia</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Maria Venzor</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
  [{v:'GDVG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas/Guardias</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sandra Pulido</div>'}, 'DVPG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV5', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Eduardo Huerta</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV6', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Claudia Díaz</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV7', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Lizbeth Negrete</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV8', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ericka Armeria</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV9', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Álvarez</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
  [{v:'GDV10', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ana García</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
  [{v:'GDV11', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Diana Corral</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
  [{v:'GDV12', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Piedra</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
  [{v:'GDV13', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Juan González</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
  [{v:'GDV14', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marina Ríos</div>'}, 'DVPT', ''],
  [{v:'GDV15', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fabiola Castruita</div>'}, 'DVPT', ''],
  [{v:'GDV16', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Daniel Martínez</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
  [{v:'GDV17', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Espinosa</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
  [{v:'GDV18', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Benavides</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
  [{v:'GDV19', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Wong</div>'}, 'DVPMN', ''],
  [{v:'GDV20', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Martha Álvarez</div>'}, 'DVPM', '']
];
</script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my attempt, **it doesn't work correctly**, but should be close
maybe you can get it to work

basically, it uses the [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to only show the rows the user has selected

this limits the chart to just the CEO
`view.setRows([0]);`

then on `'select'` find direct reports for CEO and show / hide those
`view.setRows([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);`

the main drawback being the chart appears *jumpy* when expanding / collapsing (on `'select'`)

something to check --> click on CEO, then CFO, then "Director de Tecnología de Informática -- Isela Montenegro"

something appears and hides off to the right,
but don't think that node should have any direct reports...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
  data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

  data.addRows([
    [{v:'CEO', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Carlos Lukac</div>'}, '', ''],
    [{v:'DRH', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director RH</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Luis Arturo Flores</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
    [{v:'DNCC', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional de Capillas y Cementerios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ursula Gartz</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
    [{v:'DO', f:'<a href="#">Director Operaciones</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Sosa</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
    [{v:'CFO', f:'<a href="#">CFO</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Octavio Trejo</div>'}, 'CEO', 'CFO'],
    [{v:'DNVP', f:'<a href="#">Director Nacional Ventas de Previsión</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Everardo García</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
    [{v:'DRI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director de Relaciones Institucionales</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Francisco Carriedo</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
    [{v:'DPM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Planeación y Marketing</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Oscar Chávez</div>'}, 'CEO', ''],
    [{v:'GDO', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente de Desarrollo Organizacional</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jeannette González</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
    [{v:'GerenteVacante', f:'<a href="#">Gerente de Reclutamiento y Selección</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Vacante</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
    [{v:'HectorGarcia', f:'<a href="#">Gerente Administración de RH</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Hector García Piñón</div>'}, 'DRH', ''],
    [{v:'BenjaminM', f:'<a href="#">Gerente de Relaciones Públicas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Benjamín Martínez</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
    [{v:'Gaudencia', f:'<a href="#">Gerente Servicios Complementarios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Gaudencia García</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
    [{v:'DRCVM', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Valle de México</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Víctor Hernández</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
    [{v:'DRCB', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Bajío</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jesús Campos</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
    [{v:'DRCN', f:'<a href="#">Director Regional Capillas Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sergio Nieto</div>'}, 'DNCC', ''],
    [{v:'GT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Telemarketing</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fernando Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'GOC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Operación Comercial</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ignacio Rosado</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'DRVM1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 1</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'DRVM2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 2</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Juan Salvador Díaz</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'DRVPN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle Pacífico/Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ricardo Lemus</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'DRVB', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Bajío</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sinuhé Margarito</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'DRVM1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Regional Ventas Valle México 1</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Moreno</div>'}, 'DNVP', ''],
    [{v:'DITR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Impuestos, Tesorería y Riesgos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ramón Laguna</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DAI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Auditoría Interna</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo García</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Jurídico</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Carrillo</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DPF', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Planeación FInanciera</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guillermo Perea</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Contraloría</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marco Vallejo</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DRTI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director de Tecnología de Informática</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isela Montenegro</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Gabriela Cruz</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'DCZ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Cobranza</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Pérez</div>'}, 'CFO', ''],
    [{v:'GS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente de Seguridad</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Rogelio Mendiola</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
    [{v:'GGI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente General INTECSA</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús González</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
    [{v:'DNC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Nacional Cementerios</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Rodríguez</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
    [{v:'DI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Infraestructura</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guillermo Alejandro</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
    [{v:'DNM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Nacional Mantenimiento</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Mauricio Valencia</div>'}, 'DO', ''],
    [{v:'GIN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Inteligencia de Negocio</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Arriola</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],
    [{v:'GEC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Estrategia Comercial</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fernando Flores</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],
    [{v:'GDNM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo Negocios MKT</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yoani Lorenzo</div>'}, 'DPM', ''],
    [{v:'GA1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Guadalupe Duarte</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ignacio Benitez</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA3', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Morales</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA4', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isabel Butanda</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA5', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús Loera</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA6', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María de Jesús Lira</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA7', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Obed López</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA8', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Pizaña</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GA9', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Administrativo</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Guadalupe Bueno</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GNAE', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Nacional de Activos Estratégicos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandra Mendoza</div>'}, 'DA', ''],
    [{v:'GTI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Tesorería</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Luis Arámbula</div>'}, 'DITR', ''],
    [{v:'GCC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capilla Cuernavaca</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ruben Navarro</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCCS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Sullivan</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Antonio Ruíz</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCCC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Colima</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">teresita de Jesús Gutiérrez</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCCSM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Santa Mónica</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Rodolfo Vega</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCCFC', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Félix Cuevas/LM</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Patrick Hill</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Comercial Valle México</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Teresa del Río</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCCA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Acapulco</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Luis Parra</div>'}, 'DRCVM', ''],
    [{v:'GCCAGS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Aguascalientes</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Isidro Villanueva</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
    [{v:'GCCG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Guadalajara</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Liliana Gutiérrez</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
    [{v:'GCCI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Irapuato</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marina Carreón</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
    [{v:'GCCL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios León</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Verónica Navarrete</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
    [{v:'GCCM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Morelia</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Martín Huerta</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
    [{v:'GCCMTY', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Monterrey</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Beatríz Becerril</div>'}, 'DRCB', ''],
    [{v:'GCCMXI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Mexicali</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Nora Andrade</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
    [{v:'GCCR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Reynosa</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Diana Cruz</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
    [{v:'GCCTIJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Tijuana</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Abril Solis</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
    [{v:'GCCT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Aracely Contreras</div>'}, 'DRCN', ''],
    [{v:'DCCPT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Convenios Corporativos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Roberto Valdez</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
    [{v:'GCCT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Capillas y Cementerios Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Aracely Contreras</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
    [{v:'DVPCA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Canales Alternos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yasmín Vedia</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
    [{v:'DVPVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Del Valle</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">José Cisneros</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
    [{v:'DVPP', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Poniente</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alberto Munguía</div>'}, 'DRVM2', ''],
    [{v:'DVPA', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Acapulco</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Marroquín</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
    [{v:'DVPG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Guardias</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Nidia González</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
    [{v:'DVPN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Adriana Rosales</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
    [{v:'DVPS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Sur</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Paula Alfaro</div>'}, 'DRVM1', ''],
    [{v:'GDV1', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Francisco Palacios</div>'}, 'DVPCA', ''],
    [{v:'GDV2', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Arturo González</div>'}, 'DVPCA', ''],
    [{v:'GDV3', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Yadira Ramírez</div>'}, 'DVPP', ''],
    [{v:'GDVM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas/Módulos</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Carreón</div>'}, 'DVPG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV4', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Carlos Rodríguez</div>'}, 'DVPN', ''],
    [{v:'DVPGDL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Guadalajara</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alberto Lomelí</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
    [{v:'DVPMXI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Mexicali</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Álvaro Aldana</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
    [{v:'DVPR', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Reynosa</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Lucio</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
    [{v:'DVPTIJ', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Tijuana</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Hernández</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
    [{v:'DVPT', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Torreón</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Álvarez</div>'}, 'DRVPN', ''],
    [{v:'DVPAGS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Aguascalientes</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Mario Ayala</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
    [{v:'DVPL', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión León</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Belmont</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
    [{v:'DVPI', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Irapuato</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Jorge Luna</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
    [{v:'DVPMS', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Monterrey Zona Sur</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sandra Tapia</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
    [{v:'DVPMN', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Monterrey Zona Norte</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Federico Montes de Oca</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
    [{v:'DVPM', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Director Ventas Previsión Morelia</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Maria Venzor</div>'}, 'DRVB', ''],
    [{v:'GDVG', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas/Guardias</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Sandra Pulido</div>'}, 'DVPG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV5', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Eduardo Huerta</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV6', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Claudia Díaz</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV7', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Lizbeth Negrete</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV8', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ericka Armeria</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV9', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alfredo Álvarez</div>'}, 'GDVG', ''],
    [{v:'GDV10', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Ana García</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
    [{v:'GDV11', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Diana Corral</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
    [{v:'GDV12', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Piedra</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
    [{v:'GDV13', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Juan González</div>'}, 'DVPTIJ', ''],
    [{v:'GDV14', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Marina Ríos</div>'}, 'DVPT', ''],
    [{v:'GDV15', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Fabiola Castruita</div>'}, 'DVPT', ''],
    [{v:'GDV16', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Daniel Martínez</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
    [{v:'GDV17', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alejandro Espinosa</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
    [{v:'GDV18', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Alma Benavides</div>'}, 'DVPMS', ''],
    [{v:'GDV19', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">María Wong</div>'}, 'DVPMN', ''],
    [{v:'GDV20', f:'<a href="#"><a href="#">Gerente Desarrollo de Ventas</a><div style="color:red; font-style:italic">Martha Álvarez</div>'}, 'DVPM', '']
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {allowHtml:true, allowCollapse: true};

  var viewRows = [0];
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(viewRows);

  var selection = [];
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    if (chart.getSelection().length > 0) {
      selection = chart.getSelection();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      if (data.getValue(i, 1) === data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0)) {
        if (viewRows.indexOf(i) === -1) {
          viewRows.push(i);
        } else {
          viewRows.splice(viewRows.indexOf(i), 1);
        }
      }
    }
    view.setRows(viewRows);
    chart.draw(view, options);
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart.setSelection(selection);
  });

  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: if you like this approach and can't get it to work, let me know and i'll try again when i have time...

Comment: Hi, Your post gives good hints.  I've posted my solution to the problem you mention with yours. Thank you as always, cheers!